# Win8 Grid template how to hide all items from groupeditems page?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm new about win8 and developing visual studio.

I use Grid template and i wondering...

How to hide all items, but not Group name and group box.. I have too many items and i do want all item to this page. When click group box or title, find groupdetail page and there is all this group items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Grid template won't display all your items on the `GroupedItemsPage`.  It uses the `TopItems` property in the view model to show at most 12 items.  If you look in `SampleDataSources.cs` you'll see code (with a hard coded value - sigh) of 12 in `ItemsCollectionChanged`.

So, you could modify the 12 value if you want fewer, or if you want NO items to appear on the `GroupedItemsPage`, remove the `GridView` and perhaps replace it with a `ListView` whose `ItemsSource` is the group headers, but that's a bit more work and a change in the UI, which by all means is fine to do.

These templates are just a starting point, and we'd encourage you to make changes that make sense to provide the best user experience for your app.

Comment: I use JSON parser. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Store-apps-for-Absolute-Beginners-with-C-/Part-9-Data-Binding-to-the-RecipeDataSourcecs

Comment: is possible to make one text file / group? Is there any sample?